Can Dockerfile access files outside its build context?
So supposedly I have a following file structure where '<' is current terminal directory

FolderA

text.txt


FolderB <

Dockerfile



And I want to copy text.txt into the container and print the content.
Dockerfile:
FROM alpine
COPY ../FolderA/text.txt .
CMD cat text.txt

Issues start even on the docker build . stage because when you try to do so you get following error
ERROR ...: "/text.txt": not found
(skipped few words with '...')
I was unable to find any clarifying answers on the internet. So is it possible to copy text.txt without using Docker-Compose?

If from the parent directory you docker build . -f FolderB/Dockerfile, then the left-hand side of COPY will be relative to the parent directory, and you can COPY FolderA/text.txt ..  You can never COPY ../... from a parent or sibling directory.  Those docker build options are equivalent to the Compose build: { context:, dockerfile: } options but don't require Compose.

you should firstly set a working directory and ensure that text.txt in the same directory with Dockerfile and use just one dot or use with like this
Example;
FROM alpine
COPY ../FolderA/text.txt .
CMD cat text.txt





Thank you for pointing out that I have my Dockerfile text here written with an error, I edited my question. Though my question remains the same is it possible to copy text.txt without moving text.txt. Because although my case is very specific but it is the only way I can express generic problem

yes you can copy without move. i usually use like this copy command you can try like this
FROM alpine
COPY ../FolderA/*  .
CMD cat text.txt


what is the output?
